# Android : Not able to run the application

Tags: android, cordova, angularjs, android-emulator

I am using phonegap, angularJs to create an android app. When i try to run the emulator i got  message to resolve the error first.

Error :

(skipping file '.htaccess' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')

/Users/admin/Documents/user_name/project_name/assets/www/js/angular-      1.0.6/docs/partials/api/ng.directive:a.html: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.

THis is how i included angular and cordova :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the filename `ng.directive:a.html` seems not to be allowed. Could you remove the `:` from the name?

Also, you don't need a `.htaccess` file inside your PhoneGap project.

You can remove it (the file is skipped, because as the error says, files starting with `.` are ignored).

AngularJS should work with PhoneGap (I have also a PhoneGap app using AngularJS). :)

Comment: ya after removing the whole doc folder,i was able to run it. Can you tell me the pattern which is .htaccess doesn't allow.

Comment: It's this error: "[...] due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern **'.*'**". Files starting with '.' are not allowed. On systems based on the Linux kernel (such as android), files starting with '.' are hidden files. Maybe that's why you can't include `.htaccess` :)